# Excel - 2 data validation in the same cell

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I want to combine 2 data validation into one cell. I can do it with separate cell, but had no idea on how to combining them.

First Validation: a list contains certain options for user to choose, and an others if it is not inside the list.

When Others is being selected, User can input their own data.

**First Validation Setting**

[image: First Validation Setting]

Second Validation: a cell that needs to starts with a certain format, else error message will appear. e.g. users can are only to allow to input in this format `ABC xxxxx`

**Second Validation Setting**

[image: Second Validation]

I want to combined the list validation and the custom validation to one cell `F2`. So users can choose either the options given, or choose other and input the data they want, but the format must be `ABC xxxx`.

Any suggestions and helps are appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. Sorry will update the setting again

Comment: I tried that, but failed. What I did was off the Error Alert Option during setting but that allows the user to type data in any format they want. I want them to start with "ABC" so I can perform Power Query in later stage

Comment: I would do as @pnuts suggested - Apply a number format of `"ABC "@` to the cell, then set your drop-down list to allow `1,2,3,4` and not give an error when they type something else.  Then in your Power Query (or whatever else you do) use `"ABC "&F2`.

Comment: @YowE3K Hi, so you mean I create my own format "ABC" then apply the first validation setting to it? Is it what you mean?

Comment: Yes - so that the users never enter the "ABC" part - that is just automatically displayed as part of the cell formatting.  So they can select 1, 2, 3 or 4 from the drop-down and it will display as "ABC1", "ABC2", etc, or they can just type in "xyz" and it will display as "ABCxyz".  The cell **value** won't include the "ABC" part (that is just part of the display) so you need to append that to the cell value anytime you want to use it.

Comment: Alight. Thanks for the suggestion, will test it out.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it was @pnuts suggestion :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @pnuts & @ YowE3K, with the reference from [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). I had successfully achieve what I want.

Solution: Right Click `F2` -> Format cells -> Custom -> Type "ABC "@